# Line count in file with Python erases file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, count

I'm trying to count the number of lines in a file but I'm having strange results. Below there's a MWE, I believe it speaks for itself:

```
file=open('Example.txt','r')

print(sum(1 for line in file))
print(len(file.readlines()))
```

When I run this, I get the outputs `X` (right number of lines) and `0`. So the second method is either not functioning or reading an empty variable. If I switch the order, I get the same result, so it was working but somehow the variable got erased. If I allocate a `file_1` and `file_2` with the same file and run each method with a different variable, I get X and X, so the variable gets erased after completing the action.

I also tried to change from `"r"` to `"r+"`, but no luck. Can somebody explain what is happening here?? Operations over a list should not change the list, at least that's what I've been taught.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is:

```
print(sum(1 for line in file))
```

reads the file and exhausts the iterator that provides lines.

When you then do:

```
print(len(file.readlines()))
```

you'll end up with `0` because the iterator is exhausted from the previous iteration. Use `file.seek(0)` to be able to iterate through it again.

An additional note, no need to use `'r'` when you're reading files, it is the default mode already.

---

In general, you can find out that an iterator gets exhausted after iterating through it once by checking `iter(obj) is obj`:

```
f = open('example.txt')
print(iter(f) is f) # True
```

If this is the case, `obj.__iter__` returns `self` in its implementation leading to the behavior witnessed.

If not, for example take lists:

```
l = [1, 2]
print(iter(l) is l) # False
```

the `__iter__` method returns a shiny new iterator object (for lists, this is a `list_iterator` object) that can be iterated through multiple times.

Comment: Wow thank you, I had no idea such thing could happen. Where is this iterator explicitly declared? How do I know when I'll be subject to this problem? In my experience with C and MATLAB, I have to reset the iterator, but in Python I really believed it was an internal process. The 'r' was a leftover from my original code, I'll be using 'r+', but thanks for the note!

Comment: It is a built-in so it's implemented in `C` (pretty sure located in [`fileobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/fileobject.c)). You can find out that an iterator gets exhausted after iterating through it once by checking `iter(obj) is obj`. If this is the case, `obj.__iter__` returns `self` in its implementation leading to the behavior witnessed. If not, the `__iter__` method returns a shiny new iterator object that can be  iterated through multiple times @Alegom

Comment: Do you have a suggestion about when should I watch out for this event? In this case, my file had 15 lines. Who knew the iterator would be exhausted so soon?

Comment: It got exhausted because you read through all of them. In general, try and be pragmatic. If something makes perfect sense to be allowed to iterate through many times (Pythons collections like lists, tuples, e.t.c come to mind) it probably is. If not (files are usually read-once and do things with data) then it might not be. You can and should enter the Python REPL and check with `iter(obj) is obj` if you need to be certain, though @Alegom

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you for your help, @Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard. We learn every day!